Konva.js - How to set a drag limit to avoid seeing white space
I have a code that displays a picture that can be zoomed and dragged, but when dragging or zooming, a white background is visible. I would like to have it function as an interactive map that does not have this unwanted background.
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
});
const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
const imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'images/map.svg'; // Podmień na ścieżkę do swojego zdjęcia
imageObj.onload = function () {
    const konvaImage = new Konva.Image({
        x: stage.width(),
        y: stage.height(),
        image: imageObj,
        draggable: true,
    });
    konvaImage.offsetX(imageObj.width);
    konvaImage.offsetY(imageObj.height);
    layer.add(konvaImage);
    layer.draw();
    const minZoom = 1;
    const maxZoom = 2;
    stage.on('wheel', (e) => {
        e.evt.preventDefault();
        const scaleBy = 1.05;
        const oldScale = stage.scaleX();
        const mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        let newScale = e.evt.deltaY > 0 ? oldScale / scaleBy : oldScale * scaleBy;
        newScale = Math.max(minZoom, Math.min(maxZoom, newScale));
        stage.scale({x: newScale, y: newScale});
        const newPos = {
            x: mousePos.x - (mousePos.x - stage.x()) * (newScale / oldScale),
            y: mousePos.y - (mousePos.y - stage.y()) * (newScale / oldScale),
        };
        stage.position(newPos);
        stage.batchDraw();
    });
};
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    stage.width(window.innerWidth);
    stage.height(window.innerHeight);
    layer.draw();
});

https://codepen.io/kokor-masterski/pen/MWNaVJN
I checked the konva js documentation but didn't find what I needed.

You need to add a check to determine if the position and/or zoom being applied will leave a gap around the image.  You can write one function that does both then call that from inside your zoom function and within the image.on('dragmove', ...) listener.
Lets say you have a rect as a frame for the image. Your function should call getClientRect() of the frame rect, then do the same for your image. Now you can do simple checks to determine if the position of the image will be at least matching the bounds of the frame. If not then reset the position / zoom of the image. If so, allow it.
There is a blog article with sample code here - too much to repeat in this answer.
